# Input pipe for ar

Tags: linux, unix, curl, pipe

While extracting a `deb` file, the simple `curl` pipe to `ar` is not working. I tried

```
curl http://example.com/path/to/package.deb | ar -xv -
```

and

```
curl http://example.com/path/to/package.deb | ar -xv
```

Looking at `man 1 ar`, I couldn't find any pointers to pipe usage. Does `ar` support input pipe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `ar` support input pipe?

No. It appears `ar` needs its input to be seekable, it cannot read from a fifo. At least in my Debian 9.

First of all the tool does not recognize `-` as stdin. This command

```
ar -xv -
```

returns `ar: -: No such file or directory`. Omitting the operand doesn't make the tool use its stdin either.

There is a trick to force any tool (that expects a file) to use its stdin: `/proc/self/fd/0` (other possibilities: `/dev/fd/0`, `/dev/stdin`). E.g. you can save an output stream from `whatever` as a sparse file, even if `whatever` knows nothing about sparse files; you use `cp` despite it doesn't normally read its stdin:

```
whatever | cp --sparse=always /proc/self/fd/0 output_file
```

You can try this trick with `ar`:

```
curl http://example.com/path/to/package.deb | ar -xv /proc/self/fd/0
```

but you will get `ar: /proc/self/fd/0: Illegal seek`. In my Debian `strace` revealed the tool uses `lseek(2)` with a negative offset. This fails for a pipe.

With my limited knowledge I found no apparent reason ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)#File_format_details)) to seek necessarily. Even if in theory one can parse an ar archive without seeking and going back, apparently in practice `ar` does seek.

Process substitution also creates an unseekable fifo. This will fail in the same way:

```
ar -xv <(curl http://example.com/path/to/package.deb)
```

I think there is no other way than to create a (temporary) seekable file first. In general you can do this explicitly:

```
tmpf="$(mktemp)" && {
  curl http://example.com/path/to/package.deb > "$tmpf" && ar -xv -- "$tmpf"
  rm -- "$tmpf"
}
```

In `zsh` there is another form of process substitution that creates and manages a temporary file implicitly:

```
# in zsh
ar -xv =(curl http://example.com/path/to/package.deb)
```

This one will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I'm currently working in `zsh` and I had not know about `=(...)` process substitution!

Comment: The `cp --sparse=always /proc/self/fd/0` trick is awesome! Thank you so much